# SPA (Vue), BFF and IdentityServer on IIS setup?

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, single-page-application

I'm trying to build a SPA (Vue-Based) secured with the BFF pattern and publish everything to a IIS. I follow the [Duende BFF Security Framework sample](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/bff/) but I'm struggling with getting the whole picture. Can someone explain me in the plain English how does it work?

Specifically, I have those questions:

1. SPA's BFF adaptor is a proxy that makes a heavy lifting for communication with IdentityServer, while the SPA itself communicates with BFF adaptor via its plain, unsecured HTTP interface. SPA is secure because it's inaccessible directly. Is this correct?
2. My frontend SPA is a separate project does nothing with ASP.NET. Can it continue to be so or I should move it into single ASP.NET project together with BFF adapator as in the IdentityServer sample?
3. If SPA and BFF must be in the single project, should I also bring something like [VueCliMiddleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VueCliMiddleware/) which is also a proxy, or the BFF will serve the same purpose? If I need both, how those two proxies will work together?
4. If I can keep my SPA as a separate project/site on IIS, how should I make it work with BFF adaptor? If my understanding (1) is correct, how to make a SPA be only accessible via BFF? Should I bring something like IIS ARR (reverse proxy) for this purpose? Is it feasible setup?

Comment: I've recently been trying to do the same as you and I'm having problems getting the BFF implemenation withe IdentityServer and Vue 3 to work. Did you figure out any answers to your questions or find a blog post or some other advice that helped?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. My understanding of (1) was incorrect. BFF is not a proxy for a SPA. They work together in "parallel" under same base URL. BFF backend is responsible for communication with IdentityServer and in case of successful authentication issues a cookie wich is consumed by SPA. So there are two points wich should be taken in consideration: (1) common cookies between BFF backend and SPA and (2) routing. BFF has few "endpoints" (pre-determined URLs) that should be somehow handled under the same base URL.

Comment: So, I ended up with VueCliMiddleware, SPA and BFF in a single project. This works well. Hot Reload works. Common routing for the SPA portion and for the BFF portion under single project works well. The only drawback is long build action with every debug start. Another option (SPA and BFF in separate projects) is less feasible not because of reverse proxy routing (this is relatively simple in IIS) but because of sharing cookies. It's also doable but looks way more complex.

Comment: @Niksr Were you able to get the BFF host and the SPA separated? We are using Vue 3 + Vite and would rather not have to bother with Vue related middleware in the BFF. Just curious if it is possible, and if so, how hard it is to implement?

Comment: @Daxton No, I didn't even try. Did you? Seems to be not so complex with cookie-less BFF option (server-side sessions).

Comment: @Niksr Yes, we got it working! Hot reload works and everything. This post was quite helpful for us, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing recently with IS4 and SPA (Angular in my case) and I got "almost" the same questions you have. I will try to answer you with my findings until now.

1. Your BFF and your SPA should work together. I think you could [follow this quickstart](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/js_clients/js_with_backend/) and replace the JS side with your entire SPA. I mean, you could create and AspNet Core web site to host your SPA and to serve as your BFF. The communication between your SPA and your BFF will not be "insecure", in fact, if you create aspnet controllers in your BFF they can be be fully protected by the IS4 mechanisms.
2. If you use separate projects for your SPA and your BFF, then you aren't using the BFF architecture, in fact this seems more like an SPA calling an "arbitrary" remote API. Your SPA and your BFF should work together. I suggest you to follow the QuickStart I pointed, just to "see" what is the whole idea.
3. Unfortunately, I know nothing about VUE, can't suggest anything here. But, as IS4 is very .Net oriented, I see only benefits in use AspNet website as your BFF technology.
4. As I said in the item 1 and 2. I think you shouldn't separate the SPA and the BFF projects.

Comment: Well, I already answered this in my comments. There is nothing "magical" to have SPA and BFF in a single project. The main point is common cookies. It's way more simple to keep them common in a single project but still doable to separate. It will be still BFF pattern. IS even has a "no-cookie" option to keep BFF-SPA authorization in SQL server instead of cookies, so this separation must be even simpler (I didn't try yet but am planning to).